# Filter and clone object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I have 2 arrays of objects: **itemsList** and **itemsFetched**. All of the objects inside each array have the same structure (nr of key/values). One of those keys has the same 'meaning' but a different name (**item_id** on **itemsList**, **id** on **itemsFetched** ). Their values are the same.

I need to filter the **itemsList** array and leave only the objects that have the **item_id** value equal to the **id** value on **itemsFetched**. Then copy(add) the key/value **count** from each object on the **itemsFetched** array (which matches the item_id=id) to the filtered array.

I've a working code but I'm sure it isnt the best way to solve this problem. I've already asked something similar before (regarding the 'filter' part) which solved my problem, but since I had to add the 'count' part after the filtering, I ended up refactoring the whole thing.

**itemsList** (sample)

```
[
  {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Egg",
      "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/items/egg.png"
  },
  {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Pokeball",
      "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/items/20pokeballs.png"
  },
  {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Greatball",
      "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/items/greatball.png"
  },
  { 
      "id": 401,
      "name": "Incense",
      "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/items/incense.png" 
  },
  { 
      "id": 901,
      "name": "Incubator (Unlimited)",
      "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/items/eggincubator.png"
  }
]
```

**itemsFetched** (sample)

```
[ 
  {
    "item_id": 1, 
    "count": 50,
    "unseen": true
  },
  {
    "item_id": 401,
    "count": 2, 
    "unseen": true
  },
  { 
    "item_id": 901, 
    "count": 1, 
    "unseen": true 
  }
]
```

**resultArray** (what I want in the end)

```
[
  { 
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Pokeball",
    "count": 50,
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/items/20pokeballs.png",
  },
  { 
    "id": 401,
    "name": "Incense",
    "count": 2,
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/items/incense.png"
  },
  { 
    "id": 901,
    "name": "Incubator (Unlimited)",
    "count": 1,
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/items/eggincubator.png"
  }
]
```

my current code (working)

```
let arr = [];
itemsFetched.forEach((item) => {
  itemsList.forEach((item2) => {
    if (item.item_id === item2.id) {
      arr.push({
        "id": item.item_id,
        "name": item2.name,
        "count": item.count,
        "img": item2.img
      });
    }
  });
});
```

PS: I'm able to use ES6/7 syntax/features.

Comment: Its best to do this processing on the server. Always return data formatted to the browser. Then you won't have to perform the same data manipulation on every page that needs this data.

Comment: Yes, Im aware of that. this is done server-side. one of the arrays is on a json file and its sort of a template, the other is a response to an external api call.

Comment: He try to get the id from an array. here --->> if (itemsFetched.item_id === itemsList.id)

Comment: Why so much spam ? I already told you, that's not the issue. That was a copy-paste-edit error. The question here is about efficiency, best-practices and the use of ES6/7 syntax/features. Most people seem to get it, except you.

Comment: @nip In that case kcats has the best answer. By converting the array to a hashset prevents inefficient nested loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use hash map to reduce Time complexitly, your algorithm is `O(m*n)`, The follow is `O(m+n+r)`

```
const itemsMap = itemsList.reduce((map, item) => {
    map[item.id] = item
    return map
}, {})
const results = itemsFetched
    .filter((item) => itemsMap.hasOwnProperty(item.item_id))
    .map((item) => ({
        id: item.item_id,
        name: itemsMap[item.item_id].name,
        count: item.count,
        img: itemsMap[item.item_id].img,
    }))
```

Comment: thanks for the input. I'll test that and see how it goes. (also, console logging everywhere to understand whats going on eheh)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for ... of` loop (an ES6 feature) in conjunction with `Array#map`.

This makes it much easier to `return` the merged object the first time you find a match, which is a logically optimization because neither list should contain more than one entry with a given `id`.

```js
const result = itemsFetched.map(data => {
  for (let item of itemsList) {
    if (data.item_id === item.id) {
      return {
        id: item.id,
        name: item.name,
        count: data.count,
        img: item.img
      }
    }
  }
})
```

**Snippet:**

```js
const itemsList = [{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "Egg",
  "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/items/egg.png"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Pokeball",
  "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/items/20pokeballs.png"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Greatball",
  "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/items/greatball.png"
}, {
  "id": 401,
  "name": "Incense",
  "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/items/incense.png"
}, {
  "id": 901,
  "name": "Incubator (Unlimited)",
  "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/items/eggincubator.png"
}]

const itemsFetched = [{
  "item_id": 1,
  "count": 50,
  "unseen": true
}, {
  "item_id": 401,
  "count": 2,
  "unseen": true
}, {
  "item_id": 901,
  "count": 1,
  "unseen": true
}]


const result = itemsFetched.map(data => {
  for (let item of itemsList) {
    if (data.item_id === item.id) {
      return {
        id: item.id,
        name: item.name,
        count: data.count,
        img: item.img
      }
    }
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: First, thanks for the input. I've started to look at .map but I didn't knew for ... of. I'll take a look at that. Also, if this was a "reasonable size webapp", these changes would improve the performance of the server, specially the for ... of part since it's breaking after finding a match ? Assuming yes, would that be noticable ? Or just a small detail ?

Comment: The longer your list gets, the more that difference in performance will matter. Since it's such a quick fix, I would rather be on the safe side and `return` immediately when a match is found.

Comment: Got it. Just implemented your sugestion and it's working. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

One way to improve is to use `for..of` statement instead of `forEach` for the inner loop. This helps break from the loop once the id matches. There is no direct way to break from forEach method.

```
let arr = [];
itemsFetched.forEach((item) => {
  for (let item2 of itemsList) {
    if (itemsFetched.item_id === itemsList.id) {
      arr.push({
        "id": itemsFetched.item_id,
        "name": itemsList.name,
        "count": itemsFetched.count,
        "img": itemsList.img
      });
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You meant `for ... of`, which is ES6 syntax.

Comment: @gyre yes ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Answer (score -1):

Like this?

```js
var itemsList = [
  {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Egg",
      "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/items/egg.png"
  },
  {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Pokeball",
      "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/items/20pokeballs.png"
  },
  {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Greatball",
      "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/items/greatball.png"
  },
  { 
      "id": 401,
      "name": "Incense",
      "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/items/incense.png" 
  },
  { 
      "id": 901,
      "name": "Incubator (Unlimited)",
      "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/items/eggincubator.png"
  }
];

var itemsFetched = [ 
  {
    "item_id": 1, 
    "count": 50,
    "unseen": true
  },
  {
    "item_id": 401,
    "count": 2, 
    "unseen": true
  },
  { 
    "item_id": 901, 
    "count": 1, 
    "unseen": true 
  }
]



let arr = [];
itemsFetched.forEach((item) => {
  itemsList.forEach((item2) => {
    if (item.item_id == item2.id) {
      arr.push({
        "id": item.item_id,
        "name": item2.name,
        "count": item.count,
        "img": item2.img
      });
    }
  });
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: How is this better?

Comment: What ?? My code IS working. I just want to know if there's a better way to do it, instead of 2 nested for-each + if + push. (maybe I should add Im still learning the ES6/7 features/syntax, and array related functions like .filter, .map, .includes)

Comment: sorry, but you code is not working for this:  if (itemsFetched.item_id === itemsList.id)      because you are try to get id from an array  -_-

Comment: It works. I just didnt paste the full code because I think most people understand (as you can see by the other answers)

Comment: I see what you mean. I edited the code to make it easier to understand and messed up on that part

Comment: Its item/item2 instead of the array names, obviously

Comment: ok, i understand. but if you run the code with this ---->>> if (itemsFetched.item_id === itemsList.id) the code dont work becouse the array have not ID but the objects into the array yes. are you understand?